# Thrown exception: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c, exception, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting the following error for the following code segment. I don't know what it means. Can someone tell me why I keep getting it?

> Unhandled exception at 0x5A0DB49C (msvcr110d.dll) in ConsoleApplication8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char str[]="asd asd 3, 5; 12, 525; 123, 45235;";
    int a[100]={0};
    int b[100]={0};
    int i=0;
    sscanf (str, "asd asd %d, %d; %d, %d; %d, %d;", a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1], a[2], b[2]);

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){

        printf ("%d %d\n", a[i], b[i]);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: oh, really sorry.. edited the whole code now.

Comment: I accidentally pasted a trial of mine to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for `sscanf`

```
sscanf(characterArray, "Conversion specifier", address of variables);
```

suggest that, you need `&` here in `sscanf` argument for `int` type.

```
sscanf (str, "asd asd %d, %d; %d, %d; %d, %d;", a[0], b[0], &a[1], &b[1], &a[2], &b[2]);
```

Comment: thanks man. I really didn't think about that. I was trying to solve this for at least one hour.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sscanf (str, "asd asd %d, %d; %d, %d; %d, %d;", &a[0], &b[0], &a[1], &b[1], &a[2], &b[2]);
```

instead of the `sscanf` call you've got.  Otherwise, you're probably going to get a null pointer exception (`int` array values are 0).